# Optimizations in case of multiple virtual target invocations (i.e. 1, 2, 3)

Tags: c++, clang, virtual

I have below code which actually uses 1, 2, 3 virtual call targets:

```
#include <random>
#include <memory>
#include <ctime>

struct IMath
{
   virtual ~IMath() = default;

   virtual int compute(int) = 0;
};

struct MathAlg1: IMath
{
   int compute(int i) final
   {
      return i * 17;
   }
};

struct MathAlg2: IMath
{
   int compute(int i) final
   {
      return i * 19;
   }
};

struct MathAlg3: IMath
{
   int compute(int i) final
   {
      return i * 23;
   }
};

struct MathAlg4: IMath
{
   int compute(int i) final
   {
      return i * 29;
   }
};

namespace
{
    static std::shared_ptr<int> param = std::make_shared<int>(3);

    int compute(IMath& alg, int i)
    {
       return alg.compute(i);
    }

   std::unique_ptr<IMath> alg1 = std::make_unique<MathAlg1>();
   std::unique_ptr<IMath> alg2 = std::make_unique<MathAlg2>();
   std::unique_ptr<IMath> alg3 = std::make_unique<MathAlg3>();
   std::unique_ptr<IMath> alg4 = std::make_unique<MathAlg4>();

   int monomorphicCall()
   {
      return compute(*alg1, *param);
   }

   int bimorphicCall()
   {
      return compute(*alg1, *param) + compute(*alg2, *param);
   }

   int megamorphic3Call()
   {
      return compute(*alg1, *param) + compute(*alg2, *param) + compute(*alg3, *param);
   }

    int megamorphic4Call()
   {
      return compute(*alg1, *param) + compute(*alg2, *param) + compute(*alg3, *param) + compute(*alg4, *param);
   }
}

int main(){
    return monomorphicCall();
    //return bimorphicCall();
    //return megamorphic3Call();
    //return megamorphic4Call();
 }
```

Generated ASM: (clang 6.0.0 w/ -03)

```
monomorphicCall()
    main: # @main
      mov rdi, qword ptr [rip + (anonymous namespace)::alg1]
      mov rax, qword ptr [rip + (anonymous namespace)::param]
      mov esi, dword ptr [rax]
      mov rax, qword ptr [rdi]
      mov rax, qword ptr [rax + 16]
      jmp rax # TAILCALL

bimorphicCall()
    main: # @main
      push rbx
      mov rdi, qword ptr [rip + (anonymous namespace)::alg1]
      mov rax, qword ptr [rip + (anonymous namespace)::param]
      mov esi, dword ptr [rax]
      mov rax, qword ptr [rdi]
      call qword ptr [rax + 16]
      mov ebx, eax
      mov rdi, qword ptr [rip + (anonymous namespace)::alg2]
      mov rax, qword ptr [rip + (anonymous namespace)::param]
      mov esi, dword ptr [rax]
      mov rax, qword ptr [rdi]
      call qword ptr [rax + 16]
      add eax, ebx
      pop rbx
      ret

megamorphic3Call()
    main: # @main
      push rbp
      push rbx
      push rax
      mov rdi, qword ptr [rip + (anonymous namespace)::alg1]
      mov rax, qword ptr [rip + (anonymous namespace)::param]
      mov esi, dword ptr [rax]
      mov rax, qword ptr [rdi]
      call qword ptr [rax + 16]
      mov ebx, eax
      mov rdi, qword ptr [rip + (anonymous namespace)::alg2]
      mov rax, qword ptr [rip + (anonymous namespace)::param]
      mov esi, dword ptr [rax]
      mov rax, qword ptr [rdi]
      call qword ptr [rax + 16]
      mov ebp, eax
      add ebp, ebx
      mov rdi, qword ptr [rip + (anonymous namespace)::alg3]
      mov rax, qword ptr [rip + (anonymous namespace)::param]
      mov esi, dword ptr [rax]
      mov rax, qword ptr [rdi]
      call qword ptr [rax + 16]
      add eax, ebp
      add rsp, 8
      pop rbx
      pop rbp
      ret

megamorphic4Call()
    main: # @main
      push rbp
      push rbx
      push rax
      mov rdi, qword ptr [rip + (anonymous namespace)::alg1]
      mov rax, qword ptr [rip + (anonymous namespace)::param]
      mov esi, dword ptr [rax]
      mov rax, qword ptr [rdi]
      call qword ptr [rax + 16]
      mov ebx, eax
      mov rdi, qword ptr [rip + (anonymous namespace)::alg2]
      mov rax, qword ptr [rip + (anonymous namespace)::param]
      mov esi, dword ptr [rax]
      mov rax, qword ptr [rdi]
      call qword ptr [rax + 16]
      mov ebp, eax
      add ebp, ebx
      mov rdi, qword ptr [rip + (anonymous namespace)::alg3]
      mov rax, qword ptr [rip + (anonymous namespace)::param]
      mov esi, dword ptr [rax]
      mov rax, qword ptr [rdi]
      call qword ptr [rax + 16]
      mov ebx, eax
      add ebx, ebp
      mov rdi, qword ptr [rip + (anonymous namespace)::alg4]
      mov rax, qword ptr [rip + (anonymous namespace)::param]
      mov esi, dword ptr [rax]
      mov rax, qword ptr [rdi]
      call qword ptr [rax + 16]
      add eax, ebx
      add rsp, 8
      pop rbx
      pop rbp
      ret
```

Questions/Confirmation points:

1. In the case of `monomorphicCall()` to me, it looks like there is no actual
   virtual table call, but a `jmp rax # TAILCALL`. Is this a correct assessment?
2. In case of `bimorphicCall()`, `megamorphic3Call()`, `megamorphic4Call()` it triggers the `vcalls` in all cases. Is this a correct assessment?

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to test.

Comment: Hi @xskxzr, please find the full code below. Questions updated.

Comment: Can't you edit the question and add these details into it? Such post will be deleted soon since it's not an answer.

Comment: Looks like a `virtual` call in all cases.  In `monomorphicCall` the entry from the vtable is being stored in `rax`, then control is passed directly to the `virtual` call.  Since you're directly `return`ing the result of that call, the compiler just lets the `virtual` act as though it was called directly.

Comment: I have edited the initial post. Thanks

Comment: Both of your questions seem like statements to me.

Comment: I have no idea what is being asked here. Am I just being thick?